# sample space of type of blood

Tags: probability

Every human has one type of bloods which can be any of the types $A$,$B$,$AB$ OR $O$.They also have a Rhesus factor (Rh) which is either present (+) or none (-).The medical record officer want to record this matter. By assuming that the population X in country Y has a probability of A,B,AB or O bloods of (respectively) $0.41$,$0.10$,$0.04$ and $0.45$, list the sample space for this research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample space is the set of all probable outcomes of an experiment and in your case it is {A+,A-,B+,B-,AB+,AB-,O+,O-}.
The probabilities are P(A)=0.41, P(B)=0.10,P(AB)=0.04 and P(O)=0.45.